# Angular How Resolve Data Without State

Tags: angularjs

In this question I cannot provide a code example, because I don't have a clue on how to do this.

We have a scenario where we need to resolve data, but we are not using ngRoute or ui-router and this particular place in the application.

A resolver essentially blocks execution until the resolver is resolved, then takes you to the specified state.

How can we block execution until an http get is complete?

Comment: Blocking what exactly? A controller's instantiation? App load?

Comment: Just put any thing that you want to run after the $http promise has been resolved or write your own using $q.